# bugs in mysql when connecting 2 table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1267

When I am trying to rum query I find error like

> `#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='`

My table structure are

```
CREATE TABLE `empregistration` (
  `id` int(100) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `cname` text NOT NULL,
  `cpersonname` text NOT NULL,
  `roaddress` text NOT NULL,
  `txtcity` text NOT NULL,
  `txtstate` text NOT NULL,
  `txtcountry` text NOT NULL,
  `faxno` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `contactno` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `empCat` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `empno` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ctype` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `establishyear` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `txtjobcategory` text NOT NULL,
  `cemailid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `calteremailid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `aboutcompany` text NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `conpassword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `empLogo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `paymenttype` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `regDate` int(11) default NULL,
  `countViewProf` varchar(200) default '0',
  `cntDownProf` varchar(200) default '0',
  `cntJobPost` varchar(200) default '0',
  `cntupdatejob` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '0',
  `limitjobpost` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '0',
  `limitofupdatejob` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '0',
  `limitofviewcv` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '0',
  `limitofdowncv` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '0',
  `paymentforpostjob` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '0',
  `paymentforsearchcv` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '0',
  `takenPlan` varchar(255) default '0',
  `planDate` date default NULL,
  `takenplanforpostjob` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '0',
  `postjobplandate` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '0',
  `cntJobPost1` varchar(200) default '0',
  `cntupdatejob1` varchar(200) default '0',
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Active',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=214 ;
```

and other table is

```
CREATE TABLE `blockedcompanies` (
  `blockedId` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `empId` varchar(50) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `regId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `jobSeekId` varchar(50) collate latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `blockDate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`blockedId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show your query, but i expect you're doing a where somehow with an '=' in there. Now your default collation seems to be swedish, and your 'blockedcompanies' table has a collation to latin1_general.

The error says "implicit", so you're not doing something with collation in your query. Now you have to different collation being compared. You've got to change that using `COLLATE`

check this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html

Comment: Thanks i got the solution for this problem

Answer (score 0):

when you create the table empregistration, change the final line from

```
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=214 ;
```

to

```
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=214 ;
```

and your query should start working.